# Count number of months by day in php

Tags: php, date

I want to get month between two dates. I've googled a lot but still don't have the answer.

```
$date1 = new \DateTime("2021-07-20");
$date2 = new \DateTime("2021-08-15");
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
dd($interval->m); // 0 months.
```

Above, counting `$date1` and `$date2` is less than `30 days` so it returns `0 months` which is correct. But now I want to get the result 2. It's July and August. Is there any way to get that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it ? How do you want to take the difference of 2 months, between two dates, after it is less than a month?

Comment: You don’t want the actual difference between your two dates then, you want the number of months ”covered” (or sth. like that.)

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm Yes..That's the question I wanted to ask. I want to expand my knowledge. :))

Comment: You could just increase the month of your start date in a loop, until you land “in” the month of the end date - and count how many times you have to do that (plus one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a few approaches to tackle this.

The easiest method I've found that works for all use cases involves using regular math rather than date functions. The date diff methods I've tried all gave incorrect answers at some point because of the differing number of days in a month.

```
function getCoveredMonths(DateTime $date1, DateTime $date2): int {
    $earlierDate = min($date1, $date2);
    $laterDate = max($date1, $date2);

    $earlierMonthValue = $earlierDate->format("Y") * 12 + $earlierDate->format("n");
    $laterMonthValue = $laterDate->format("Y") * 12 + $laterDate->format("n");
    
    return $laterMonthValue - $earlierMonthValue + 1;
}

// Your example
$date1 = new DateTime("2021-07-20");
$date2 = new DateTime("2021-08-15");
var_dump(getCoveredMonths($date1, $date2));
// 2: July + August

// Same month
$date3 = new DateTime("2021-07-15");
$date4 = new DateTime("2021-07-20");
var_dump(getCoveredMonths($date3, $date4));
// 1: July

// Day overflow test (01-30 + 1 month = 02-30 which overflows to 03-02)
$date5 = new DateTime("2021-01-30");
$date6 = new DateTime("2021-03-01");
var_dump(getCoveredMonths($date5, $date6));
// 3: January + February + March

// Year pass test
$date7 = new DateTime("2021-12-20");
$date8 = new DateTime("2022-02-15");
var_dump(getCoveredMonths($date7, $date8));
// 3: December + January + February

// Wrong order ($date2 is before $date1)
$date9 = new DateTime("2021-10-20");
$date10 = new DateTime("2021-08-15");
var_dump(getCoveredMonths($date9, $date10));
// 3: August + September + October
```

Comment: That's great. I've been searching all day. Thank you very much +1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$origin = new \DateTime('2020-08-01');
$target = new \DateTime('2021-12-01');
$interval = $origin->diff($target);
echo (($interval->format('%y') * 12) + $interval->format('%m'));

// output is 16 months

?>
```

Comment: This does not give the desired result for the dates from the example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate with the full months, you have to calculate from the 1st of the start month to the 1st after the end of the month.

```
$date1 = new \DateTime("2021-07-20");
$date2 = new \DateTime("2021-08-15");

//
$date1->modify('first day of this Month');  //2021-07-01
$date2->modify('first day of next Month');  //2021-09-01

$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
$countMonth = $interval->m;  //2
```